I need to know whether Lead(II)Bisulfate is soluble because I couldn't find any information on it online
I need to know if Pb(HSO4)2 [Lead(II)Bisulfate] is soluble.

Soluble in what?

It is rather more about solubility of PbSO4 in environment, where TD activity of SO4^2- is strongly diminished by extremely high TD activity of H+(solv). I am not aware if there is known solid Pb(HSO4)2.

Lead sulfate $\ce{PbSO4}$ is insoluble in water and diluted aqueous sulfuric acid solutions. But $\ce{PbSO4}$ is partially soluble in concentrated sulfuric acid. This solution is destroyed when sulfuric acid is diluted with water. Then lead precipitates downs as lead sulfate $\ce{PbSO4}$. So it is admitted that lead sulfate is transformed into soluble $\ce{Pb(HSO4)2}$ by concentrated sulfuric acid.
The equation for synthesizing this $\ce{Pb(HSO4)2}$ is :  $$\ce{PbSO4 + H2SO4 -> Pb(HSO4)2}$$ and this compound is decomposed by dilution into water according to :  $$\ce{Pb(HSO4)2 + 2 H2O -> PbSO4 + 2 H3O^+ + SO4^{2-}}$$
Edit : The solubility of PbSO4 is well described in old books of qualitative analysis. For example F. P. Treadwell, Qualitative Analysis. I only have its French translation : Analyse quantitative, Dunod Paris 1924, p. 204. The two previous equations are taken from this book.
$\ce{PbSO4}$ solubility is also detailed in Wikipedia (I copy) : Lead sulfate dissolved in concentrated $\ce{H2SO4}$ produce an acidic salt, according to :
$$\ce{PbSO4(s) + H2SO4(l) ⇌ Pb(HSO4)2(aq) }$$ Unfortunately, there is no information that $\ce{Pb(HSO4)2}$ does exist in the solid state.

"[I]t is observed that PbSO4
is partially soluble in concentrated sulfuric acid." By whom? A reference or two might work well here.

The solubility of $\ce{PbSO4}$ is well described in old books of qualitative analysis. For example F. P. Treadwell, Qualitative Analysis. I only have the French translation (Analyse quantitative), Dunod Paris 1924, p. 204. The equations shown in my answer 2 hours ago are taken from this reference.

The article on Lead sulfate taken from Wikipedia states (I copy) : Lead(II) sulfate can be dissolved in concentrated HNO3, HCl, H2SO4 producing acidic salts or complex compounds, and in concentrated alkali giving soluble tetrahydroxidoplumbate(II) [Pb(OH)4]2− complexes.
PbSO4(s) + H2SO4(l) ⇌ Pb(HSO4)2(aq)
PbSO4(s) + 4 NaOH(aq) → Na2Pb(OH)4 + Na2SO4(aq)

OK, but please put your references in the answer, not in comments.
